# Restkit on Xcode 4.5 GM does not work on iOS 6 device - file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, restkit

I have been using Xcode 4.4.1 and Restkit has been working perfectly on Simulator and Device. Since I upgraded to Xcode 4.5 yesterday, Restkit works fine on the Simulator, but when I try to run on my iOS 6 device, I get compile errors;

```
d: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-Name/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRestKit.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-Name/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRestKit.a
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKObjectManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
```

What does this mean and how do I fix this issue? Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have pushed a branch to the RestKit Github repository that should address the build issues with the iOS 6 SDK. I was not able to duplicate the build errors in my project (I am diverged from the master branch significantly), but believe the fix is accurate.

Could someone experiencing the issue please switch to the `bugfix/930-arm7s-compatibility` branch and advise if the fix is good on Github? There is a Github issue tracking this at: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/930

Comment: I have merged this fix to RestKit master and development branches and tagged it as 0.10.3. Cheers!

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Thanks Blake! Amazing framework you've made.

Comment: I added RestKit as a git submodule as instructed, so a simple git pull did the trick. Very nice, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might need to **recompile** the RestKit Framework using **iOS6 SDK** and then add the libRestKit.a framework into your project.

**EDIT:**

Its been fixed. You should make the changes to your project files from [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/930)

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more what you mean by recompile it using iOS6 SDK, i'm not sure how I would do that.

Comment: build the RestKit framework Code by setting iOS6 as Base SDK and then check if you are getting the libRestKit.a file as Product. If not then RestKit support for iOS6 has not been implemented yet

Comment: Opened the RestKit project to iOS6, build and imported the framework to my current project again - works perfectly.

Comment: mine compiles on the simulator, but not the device.

Comment: I removed restkit and imported it back in, the base SDK is iOS6 but it still doesn't work on the device, just the simulator.

Comment: checkout the new EDIT, which provides fix for your issue

Comment: Vimal,the edit link is the not working... can you post link again.

Comment: Link has been replaced.. its the same link provided above by Blake Watters

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem

this thread solved my problem 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12537677/2183952
and most importantly make sure "Build Active Architecture Only" is set to "No" in the build settings of both the "Restkit" project and your own project.

Answer (score 0):

Restkit is compiled for armv6/armv7, so it can not work on armv7s, many the third Lib would meet the same question.