# After upgrading Xcode to 4.5, Restkit 10.0 project not compiling for iOS 5.1 device

Tags: ios5, restkit, xcode4.5

Just upgraded to Xcode 4.5. Figured out after getting bugs in my app in the 6.0 simulator that I had to redownload the 5.1 simulator. Hurray, that worked! but....

When I went and tried to run against my iPad1 with iOS 5.1.1 on it, I get a whole bunch of restkit compile errors.

Getting : "Linker command failed with exit code 1"

Do I have to upgrade to Resktit 10.3 ? I don't see anything in the github history regarding Xcode 4.5 fixes...

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, just noticed the following warning:

```
ignoring file /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PlascoTrac-ginlxeicfonetcaicpyggfpyuxrj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRestKit.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PlascoTrac-ginlxeicfonetcaicpyggfpyuxrj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRestKit.a
```

so I went to the Restkit target and changed the architecture to

```
Standard (armv7, armv7s)
```

and voila!

Leaving this question and answer here because I don't see the exact equivalent here and it might be useful to others,

Cheers.