# Xcode Error after upgrading to iOS 6 SDK and Xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, restkit

I have an application running successfully on Xcode 4.2 iOS 5.1, when i updated to Xcode 4.5 to make the application compatible with iOS 6, when i run the application it gives an error

```
"Apple Mach-O linker error: no such file or directory: '/Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RestKit/RestKit'"
```

Any help regarding that is really appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12537605/859742

Comment: yeah change the architecture and it should work

Comment: @IlkerBaltaci Changed the Architecture Standard (armv7, armv7s), i removed the armv6 from beside of it but still getting the same error.
please note that i moved the project from a mac to another...

Comment: @ilight Changed the Architecture Standard (armv7, armv7s), i removed the armv6 from beside of it but still getting the same error. please note that i moved the project from a mac to another mac..

Answer (score 0):

if you have moved the project from one comp to another you might have nor copied the restkit framework to you project folder on the old mac.Try to remove the restkit and readd it under build phases

Comment: i downloaded the latest version of rest kit and installed it from the scratch, still in vain