# Xcode restKit error after updating into Xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, restkit

I have an application running successfully on Xcode 4.2 iOS 5.1, when i updated to Xcode 4.5 to make the application compatible with iOS 6, when i run the application it gives an error

```
Apple Mach-O linker error: no such file or directory: '/Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RestKit/RestKit'
```

Note that i have moved the whole project from a Mac that was running xcode 4.2 into another Mac running Xcode 4.5

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537605/after-upgrading-xcode-to-4-5-restkit-10-0-project-not-compiling-for-ios-5-1-dev

Comment: @adig tried it, and did not work!!

Answer (score 0):

Just goto BuildSettings of the Project and remove armv7s from Valid architecture